# How to project an image through the lens?

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, shaders, eevee-render-engine

[image]
I have an image (on the top in printscreen 1), the lens, and the white plane (screen) under the lens. I expect to see projection of the image, I change position of the lens - nothing matters, the screen is black.

[image]
I also have a small cub and you can see that refraction does work (you can see refracted cub).
Is there any way to manage that? Eevee (2.8+) or blender internal (2.79-), no Cycles.
This is 2.8 file [image]

Answer (score 2):

EEVEE is not supporting indirect lighting right now. 
You still can use *Irradiance Volume* and *indirect light projection* to **Bake** those effect into your scene.

[image]If you set a proper light map, it might work

Refraction won't provide any light into the scene maybe. And it use some algorithm to achieve it in EEVEE, which is not focus on project light. In these kind of problem, we usually adopt **ray tracing** to mock the effect, which EEVEE is not good at it. EEVEE is rasterization rendering engine.

Comment: Wow, I've never dealt with Irradiance Volume and indirect light projection. I'll try. What about 2.79 blender internal render? Can it be solved there?

Comment: Same as EEVEE. Both are rasterization, not ray tracing. It'll be very difficult to solve the problem unless rewriting the shader program like all 3A games did.

Comment: Got it.
I tried Irradiance Volume and indirect light projection and it didn't work. Maybe I did something wrong but I only get shadows of the lens on the screen but not the image. I turned off the lights, made the image just a small plane with emission shader (10 units emit), and yes, I see the indirect lighting from the image on the screen and the shadow under the lens. I tried to change lens position, something changes, but I can not see plane as an image under the lens anyway.